# Spritekit how to not veer off

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm building a pacman style maze game. 
I can apply impulse and limit it to whatever vertical or horizontal direction as desired on the hero.

However, when I add physics body sprites for walls, it gets weird. 
I have set the hero physics body and the walls to have no bounce.

Running head on into a wall it stops dead like expected. 
But if I then change direction and move along the wall I veer off at a slight angle from the wall. 
Any ideas what causes this and how to avoid it?
I want to only move in vertical and horizontal straight lines.

Comment: How important to you is using physics for the movement, rather than just moving the hero node?

Comment: I get what you're saying but I need it to move in one direction until pointed another direction or hitting a wall and stopping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution here is slightly counter intuitive. 
Rather than using applyForce: or applyImpulse: family of methods on the physicsBody, use runAction:forKey: on the sprite itself. 
For any change in direction, removeAction:forKey: just before calling runAction:forKey:  to keep things orthogonal. 
(Otherwise there will be a brief angular movement )

The other trick here is to find an appropriate speed for distance. Too fast and it will fly through walls. (Bug?)
Then apply the speed and distance with a multiplier based on the size of your scene. 
The total distance should be something greater than possible in any direction. 
That keeps the thing moving until it hits a wall or you tell it to move in a different direction.

This works really well.

Using the physics body movement, it seems best suited to a platformer situation where you have a gravity.

In a top down view, there isn't normally gravity. 
( though it is imaginable that you could want something that exerts gravity on a sprite to suck it in)